# Firefox's networks speed on proxy

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I was wondering if there is a built-in API to measure network's speed (in and out) in Firefox. If not is there any way to measure the speed from nsiChannel?

Comment: Awesome question, i would love to see the answer myself. I know its possible, I just don't know how. This would be an excellent addon to tell you how fast things are going, i would use it! Especially when you are testing out different proxy addresses! Are you planning on making this addon?

Comment: Just one addition to the question: I know that FoxyProxy extension somehow uses the speed over proxified network to rotate its icon based on the total speed that passes through proxy. I wasn't able to detect how exactly it works though.